# Как исправить эту ошибку Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Когда запускаю команду npm i в командной строке из папки проекта начинается скачивание файлов и вылазит такая ошибка:

```
1663 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."unreachable-branch-t'
1663 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
1663 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
1663 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
1663 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
1663 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
1664 verbose cwd C:\Users\Office\Desktop\Project
1665 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1666 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
1667 verbose node v8.11.1
1668 verbose npm  v5.6.0
1669 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."unreachable-branch-t'
1670 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "blank",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mikle888",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.3",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-csscomb": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

Раньше все было нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать с этим?

**UPD:** версия ноды `8.11.1`, версия npm - `5.6.0`.

Comment: Приведите лог текстом, пожалуйста. Также, покажите содержание файла `package.json`.

Comment: Вот тут package.json - http://justnotepad.com/get/9c92d9d5f8c3c611eb9fb072f08fb029. Вот тут лог -http://justnotepad.com/ru/get/1d791ec72747b7053dff97bca13dd030. Пароль и там, и там - 11111111

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` пробовали? Какие версии ноды и npm?

Comment: Нет, что делает эта команда? Node - 8.11.1, npm - 5.6.0

Comment: Кэш чистит https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: @Suvitruf ,огромное спасибо!

Comment: Очистка кэша помогла?

Comment: Да, все установилось.

Comment: Вот и хорошо. Отметьте тогда мой ответ как принятый, чтоб и другим помогло, если столкнутся с такой проблемой ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Очистка кэша](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) командой `npm cache clean --force` частенько помогает в таких случаях.